# Python - Facebook connect without browser based-redirect

Tags: python, facebook, oauth, soa

title might be a bit of a misnomer.

I have two subdomains setup in a web application, one for the application frontend at www. (which is using a loose PHP router coupled with backbone, require, and jquery for UI) and a data tier setup at data. (built entire in python utilizing Werkzeug)

We decided to go to this kind of architecture since at some point mobile app will be integrated into the equation, and they can just as easily send HTTP connections to the data subdomain.  The data subdomain renders all its responses in JSON, which the JS frontend expects universally as a response be it a valid query response or an error.

This feels like the most organized arrangement I've ever had on a project, until Facebook connect appeared on the manifesto.

Ideally, I'd like to keep as much of the 'action' of the site behind the scenes on the data subdomain, especially authentication stuff, so that the logic is available to the phones and mobile devices as well down the line if need be.  Looking into the facebook docs, it appears however that the browser and its session object are critical components in their OAuth flow.

> User authentication and app authorization are handled at the same time
>   by redirecting the user to our OAuth Dialog. When invoking this
>   dialog, you must pass in your app id that is generated when you create
>   your application in our Developer App (the client_id parameter) and
>   the URL that the user's browser will be redirected back to once app
>   authorization is completed (the redirect_uri parameter). The
>   redirect_uri must be in the path of the Site URL you specify in
>   Website section of the Summary tab in the Developer App. Note, your
>   redirect_uri can not be a redirector.

I've done this before in PHP and am familiar with the process, and it's a trivial matter of about 3 header redirects when the logic in question has direct access to the browser.  My problem is that the way our new app is structured, all the business logic is sequestered on the other subdomain.  What are my options to simulate the redirect?  can I have the python subdomain send the HTTP data, receiving it from the www domain using CURL like all the other requests?  **Can I return a json object to the user's browser that instructs on doing the redirects?  Will Facebook even accept requests from a data subdomain, whose redirect_uri is at subdomain www?**  I find that last sentence in the quoted section probably discounts that as a possibility, but I've looked through their docs and it doesn't explicity say that this would be treated as a violation.

Has anyone had any experience setting up something like this with Facebook with a similar architecture?  Perhaps I should just fold and put the FB login logic directly into PHP and handle it there.

Thanks!